# Ionic Android Notifications Stacking

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

**ISSUE**

Notifications do not stack in the tray when sent to android devices, instead they overwrite the previous unread notification belonging to the same app.

Notification Payload that is being sent to `Ionic`.

```
{  
   "send_to_all":true,
   "profile":"dev",
   "notification":{  
      "title":"Title",
      "message":"Test Message 2!",
      "android":{  
         "collapseKey":true,
         "stack":4,
         "payload":{  
            "type":"annoucement"
         },
         "sound":"default"
      }
   }
}
```

Notification Object Received ( Viewed locally using adb logcat):

```
{  
   "sound":"default",
   "title":"Title",
   "message":"Test Message 2!",
   "additionalData":{  
      "payload":{  
         "type":"annoucement"
      },
      "google.message_id":"0:1470668857644329%e03d0952f9fd7ecd",
      "collapse_key":"do_not_collapse",
      "foreground":true
   }
}
```

I also tried setting the `notId` as recommended in the push plugin docs and sent multiple notifications with unique `notId` as follows:

INPUT to ionic API:

```
{  
   "send_to_all":true,
   "profile":"dev",
   "notification":{  
      "title":"Title",
      "message":"Test Message 2!",
      "android":{  
         "collapseKey":true,
         "stack":4,
         "payload":{  
            "type":"annoucement"
         },
         "sound":"default",
        "data": {
            "notId": 2
        }
      }
   }
}
```

OUTPUT as seen in logcat

```
{  
   "sound":"default",
   "title":"Title",
   "message":"Test Message 2!",
   "additionalData":{  
      "payload":{  
         "type":"annoucement"
      },
      "data":{  
         "notId":2
      },
      "google.message_id":"0:1470670019771364%e03d0952f9fd7ecd",
      "coldstart":false,
      "collapse_key":"do_not_collapse",
      "foreground":false
   }
}
```

As you can see that there is no indication what so ever regarding stacking here so it makes sense that it is not working, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong or is it actually a bug.

Comment: Remove the "collapse_key" field

Answer (score 0):

If you send a notification with a "collapse_key" and then send a new notification with a collapse_key having the same value, then gcm (server) overrides the older notification and sends only the newest notification.  So just remove the "collapse_key" field.

You can get more information on the topic by reading the "Collapsible messages" [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: This did not work, I tried the first payload with `collapseKey` set to 123 and then reset it with `collapseKey` set to `456` and still it overwrote the previous message and the "collapse_key" is always coming in as "do_not_collapse",

Comment: @NewUser can you try removing the field and sending the notification again.

Comment: @NewUser are you incrementing "notId" with every push, The first notification must contain "notId": 1 , the next "notId": 2 and so on.

Comment: Yes, I did increment the notId